# No aparece imagen y no puedo centrarla

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente código y no puedo hacer que aparezca la imagen y no sé como centrarlo (que vaya sobre los 3 puntos).

```css
:root {
  --main-color: #ecf0f1;
  --point-color: #D31818;
  --size: 5px;
}

.loader {
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center; 
  justify-content: center;  
    z-index: 100000;
}

.loader__element {
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: var(--size) solid var(--point-color);
  margin: calc(var(--size)*2);
}

.loader__element:nth-child(1) {
  animation: preloader .6s ease-in-out alternate infinite;
}
.loader__element:nth-child(2) {
  animation: preloader .6s ease-in-out alternate .2s infinite;
}

.loader__element:nth-child(3) {
  animation: preloader .6s ease-in-out alternate .4s infinite;
}

@keyframes preloader {
  100% { transform: scale(2); }
}
```

```html
<div class="imagen">
  <img  src="https://i.imgur.com/BLtvE6n.png">
</div>

<div class="loader">
  <span class="loader__element"></span>
  <span class="loader__element"></span>
  <span class="loader__element"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Te refieres a algo así como en [este enlace](https://jsfiddle.net/bau79tch/)?

Comment: @masterguru sí, pero cómo puedo hacer para que la imagen aparezca encima de los 3 puntos flotantes y que no se vea tan transparente?

Comment: Hazte un gif animado pues... no se hacerlo, la verdad :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres que la imagen aparezca sobre los tres puntos, el problema está en que la capa **.loader** se superpone a la capa **.imagen** debido a los atributos CSS *width*, *height*, *position*, *top*, *left* y *z-index*.

Para solucionarlo, podrías meter tanto **.loader** como **.imagen** dentro de otra capa que incluya los atributos CSS que hacen que **.loader** se superponga y cubra toda la pantalla: *width*, *height*, *position*, *top* y *left*.

He modificado el nombre de las clases para ajustarlas al método BEM, pero sería algo así:

```css
:root {
  --main-color: #ecf0f1;
  --point-color: #d31818;
  --size: 5px;
}

.loader {
  z-index: 1000000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: var(--main-color);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.loader__image {
  /* Por si quieres añadir algún atributo CSS a la imagen */
}

.loader__animation {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: calc(var(--size) * 2);
}

.loader__animation-element {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: var(--size) solid var(--point-color);
  margin: calc(var(--size) * 2);
}

.loader__animation-element:nth-child(1) {
  animation: preloader .6s ease-in-out alternate infinite;
}

.loader__animation-element:nth-child(2) {
  animation: preloader .6s ease-in-out alternate .2s infinite;
}

.loader__animation-element:nth-child(3) {
  animation: preloader .6s ease-in-out alternate .4s infinite;
}

@keyframes preloader {
  100% { transform: scale(2); }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <img  src="https://i.imgur.com/BLtvE6n.png" class="loader__image">
  <div class="loader__animation">
    <span class="loader__animation-element"></span>
    <span class="loader__animation-element"></span>
    <span class="loader__animation-element"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola, esto solucionó mi problema. Muchas gracias!